# JQuery conflict in Joomla 1.5 site

Tags: jquery

I'm having some sort of a conflict with JQuery. I'm developing the site in Joomla, which appears to be complicating this issue a little more. Site is at http://www.deepwaterchurch.com/cms

I had an earlier issue whereby the slider I was using (utilizing JQuery) was conflicting with Mootools. I was able to install a plugin via Joomla that enabled JQuery in no-conflict mode (**in the head**); problem solved.
Fast forward... I have added a JQuery script **in the body** of my document to parse an XML file (podcast), but now my slider won't work any more! If I delete line 366...

```
<script src="/cms/scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

...then the slider works fine, but my XML-generated podcast doesn't work. I've tried various iterations to enable NoConflict in the body, but it doesn't seem to work.

I'll be the first to admit that I'm kind of hacking my way through and learning as I go. Can anyone offer any insight? Thanks!

Comment: jquery uses mootools which create conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Underneath that line you have mentioned you are referencing jQuery again using $. If you remove the line you have mentioned which is not needed since you have included jQuery already in the  part of your document. Then change all instances of $ to jQuery. For example change

```
$(function() {
    //code
});
```

to this

```
jQuery(function() {
    //some code
});
```

Comment: You can also wrap your jQuery code to allow you access to `$` without causing conflicts by using `(function($) {/* your original code that uses $ */ })(jQuery);`

Comment: Perfect!  So simple.  I'm really and truly a novice with this.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

jquery uses mootools which create conflict

```
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

     // Use jQuery via $j(...)
     $j(document).ready(function(){
       $j("div").hide();
     });
```

Comment: I don't think it's true to say that jquery uses mootools. They're in conflict because they both want to be referenced as $.

Comment: I believe you are incorrect, sir. Do you have a reference to your statement?